# How to scan uploaded file for virus on linux?

Tags: linux, malware

Just like the title, is there any antivirus that i can run from command prompt on linux to make sure user uploaded files are virus free?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd add that technically, you can't be absolutely sure that the files are virus free, just that they don't match anything in the heuristic scan or signature database...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what about http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/

Comment: Agreed. Install ClamAV and then use clamscan utility

Comment: +1 for ClamAV. Used it in a mail server and worked very well, and was designed for mail servers so it works as a fast plugin to other applications that can call scripts.

Comment: +1 Clamav is the weapon of choice here.

Comment: Command prompt is OK, but a best practice is to run ClamAV automatically on all network writable partitions, such as Samba shares and FTP uploads.

Comment: I thought clamav is more suitable for mail. It's good for normal files as well?

Comment: @Patrick, You can use ClamAV for almost anything.  Being the only deployed FreeSoftware AV (AFAIK), there are plugins for almost everything you would want to use AV with.  Obviously, clamscan does the on demand scanning.